# PHP Category Tree to Array for Laravel Select Box

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am struggling with getting an array output to populate a select box in Laravel. Basically, with Laravel you can send an array to populate a select via blade.

```
[
    '1'=>'Parent Category 1',
    '2'=>'Sub Category Name 1', 
    '3'=>'Parent Category 2',
    '4'=>'Sub Category Name'
 ]
```

I am currently doing a quick mock to populate a html list and that outputs correctly, but after hours of researching I am just lost on how to convert this so it outputs as an array like the example above.

So my code looks something like this:

```
public function categories($parent_id) {
    $q = $this->region->select(['title','id'])->where('parent_id','=',$parent_id)->orderBy('sort','asc')->get();
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($q as $row)
    {
        echo '<li>';
        echo $row->title;
        echo '</li>';
        $this->categories($row->id);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

^ This outputs

```
Parent Category 1 
  -Subcat  
  -Subcat

Parent Category 2 
  -Subcat  
  -Subcat
```

Any suggestion on how to convert that to a single array would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you want a plain array whitout structure?

Comment: A plain array should work as long as it keeps the orderBy, I basically just need it to output like the first example. If I could indent the sub cat with like a dash --  that would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I can't try so code may has bugs

```
public function categories_list($parent_id, $Indent)  {
   $q = $this->region->select(['title','id'])->where('parent_id','=',$parent_id)->orderBy('sort','asc')->get();
   $arr = array();
   foreach($q as $row) 
      {
            $arr[] =  $Indent . $row->title;
            $newIndent = $Indent == '' ? '  -- ' : '  '. $Indent;
            $arr = array_merge($arr, $this->categories($row->id, $newIndent));
        }
   return $arr;
}

$array = $this->categories_list($id, '');
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting Undefined variable: arr.

Comment: @limit added initialization

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that, but now get, array_merge(): Argument #3 is not an array.